# React useState to dynamically toggle multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to toggle the faq buttons, basically when button1 is clicked -> state1 is turned true (tooltip is opened) -> button2 is clicked -> state2 is true, state1 is turned false, tooltip closes. This is what I currently have

```
const App = () => {

const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const faqTipBtns = ['faqBtn1', 'faqBtn2', 'faqBtn3'];

const FaqtipIcon = (id) => {
     return(
         <button id = {id}
          onClick = {() => toggleFaqTipBtn()}>
          <FaqtipIcon isOpen = {isOpen}/>
         </button>
     )
};

const toggleFaqTipBtn = () => {

  {faqTipBtns.map((id) => {
        setIsOpen((prev) => !prev)
})}


   return (
     <form>
        <RadioGroup>
         <div>
            <Radio
               id='idA'
               label = 'SomeLabel'/>
               {FaqtipIcon('idA')}
           </div>
           {isOpen && (
                <div>
                   <FaqtipContent
                     isOpen = {isOpen}
                     content = {<p>Some Content</p>} 
                    />
                </div>   
        </RadioGroup>
     </form>
)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

###### React useState to dynamically toggle multiple buttons

I understand your question like that show tooltip that related of button.
[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-http-tzjc97)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedBtn, setSelectedBtn] = useState("");
  const faqTipBtns = ["faqBtn1", "faqBtn2", "faqBtn3"];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>show Tooltip that related with his button</h1>
      {faqTipBtns.map((button) => (
        <div>
          {selectedBtn === button ? <div> Tooltip {button}</div> : <div />}
          <button onClick={() => setSelectedBtn(button)}>{button}</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```